# How does location authorization work when a user has multiple roles?

Tags: asp.net, web-config, forms-authentication

My web.config has this authorization rule:

```
  <location path="Views/Administrator">
    <system.web>
      <authorization>
        <allow roles="roleA, roleB" />
        <deny users="*" />
      </authorization>
    </system.web>
  </location>
```

**What does this mean?**

When I test the login process, a user in *roleA* or a user in *roleB* is able to access all content under Views/Administrator, BUT when a user logs in with *roleC* they are denied access.  So far this makes sense.  At first glance, this implies that a user with *roleA* or *roleB* is allowed. **BUT** when I assign roles *roleA* and *roleC* to the same user and try to login I am denied.  This implies that the authorization rule looks at all the roles a user is in and denies the user access if the user doesn't have all of the roles defined in the `<allow />` tag.

So: "How does location authorization work when a user has multiple roles?"

Answer (score 3):

Ok, so I've just created a new web application that uses the default role manager stuff. I created three roles, roleA, roleB, roleC. and in my application I added the same config entry that you use above but changed the path to the default about page "About.aspx".

After testing different role configurations, roles seem to work exactly as one would expect. If a user is a member of multiple roles, for example roleA and roleC, if you config is setup the way you have it above, Allow "roleA, roleB" my user gets access regardless of order. Take away roleA in the config, and my user no longer has access. Take away roleB and readd roleA, my user has acess again, readd them both, user has access.

Edit 2 - Removing Image with "RoleGroup" as I beleive it add's confustion.

http://www.asp.net/security/tutorials/role-based-authorization-cs. 
 Has a pretty good explanation of how role based auth works. No great info on multiple roles tho.

Also as a side note you can check roles programaticaly which is a little more cumbersome to maintain but you can then handle authorization whatever way you like, I have personally done this in past projects to restrict access to different pages for users and it has worked out pretty well for me.

https://web.archive.org/web/20181010194753/http://www.4guysfromrolla.com:80/articles/082703-1.2.aspx

Edit - Adding info regarding my test.

To further explain how i am testing:

I created a basic user, and 3 roles in the web administration tool. Created 3 roles. And Assigned roleA and roleC to my user.

[image: Web Admin]

From there here is my config file. Which is the default web config with a new project with your settings added above.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="ApplicationServices" connectionString="data source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Integrated Security=SSPI;AttachDBFilename=|DataDirectory|\aspnetdb.mdf;User Instance=true"
     providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
</connectionStrings>
<system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0" />

 <authentication mode="Forms">
   <forms loginUrl="~/Account/Login.aspx" timeout="2880" />
 </authentication>

<membership>
  <providers>
    <clear/>
    <add name="AspNetSqlMembershipProvider" type="System.Web.Security.SqlMembershipProvider" connectionStringName="ApplicationServices"
         enablePasswordRetrieval="false" enablePasswordReset="true" requiresQuestionAndAnswer="false" requiresUniqueEmail="false"
         maxInvalidPasswordAttempts="5" minRequiredPasswordLength="6" minRequiredNonalphanumericCharacters="0" passwordAttemptWindow="10"
         applicationName="/" />
  </providers>
</membership>

<profile>
  <providers>
    <clear/>
    <add name="AspNetSqlProfileProvider" type="System.Web.Profile.SqlProfileProvider" connectionStringName="ApplicationServices" applicationName="/"/>
  </providers>
</profile>

<roleManager enabled="true">
  <providers>
    <clear />
    <add connectionStringName="ApplicationServices" applicationName="/"
      name="AspNetSqlRoleProvider" type="System.Web.Security.SqlRoleProvider" />
    <add applicationName="/" name="AspNetWindowsTokenRoleProvider"
      type="System.Web.Security.WindowsTokenRoleProvider" />
  </providers>
</roleManager>

</system.web>

<system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
</system.webServer>


 <location path="About.aspx">
    <system.web>
        <authorization>
            <allow roles="roleA, roleB" />
            <deny users="*" />
        </authorization>
    </system.web>
 </location>
```

Comment: Thanks for your response.  I'm not using RoleGroups.  RoleGroups look to be associated with an asp.net control.  Problem I'm having is my user gets redirected back to the login page as soon as I assign an additional role that doesn't exist in the comma separated allow role list.

Comment: @subt13 - "RoleGroups" is only what the article calls roles.  They're not associated with an asp.net control.

Comment: @Dylan - if I understood correctly, you are not running into the same problem as me.  I am using a custom role provider and membership provider, but I don't see why that would cause this issue.  I don't even know if the location stuff even hits my custom role provider.

Comment: @subt13 - correct my default webforms application seemed to handle the multiple roles as if a user belonged to one role in the comma delimited list of allowed roles it would have access, regardless of order or how many roles were in the allowed list. From here I guess I don't know why things wouldn't act the same... you could decompile system.web and look into how the authorization routine works if you really wanted to get into the nitty gritty of things but you would need a decompiler to do so like Reflector or Boomerang.

Comment: did this help answer your question? Or did you need further help with this?

Answer (score -1):

Try doing this programmatically instead, as previously mentioned.
if(User.IsInRole("RoleC") )
{
... etc.
}

Comment: I see this as a workaround, even so it doesn't really answer my question.